# How to solve Twilio error: "Invalid messaging binding address"?

Tags: c#, twilio, twilio-api

I'm following this [Twilio's tutorial](https://www.twilio.com/docs/conversations/api/conversation-participant-resource).
I'm trying to add a participant to a conversation, but I'm getting this error. I've searched online. The only [article](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/errors/50407) I found related to the issue says to make sure that the format of the phone number is valid. However, I'm still getting this error:

> Twilio.Exceptions.ApiException: Invalid messaging binding address
> at Twilio.Clients.TwilioRestClient.ProcessResponse(Response response)
> at Twilio.Clients.TwilioRestClient.Request(Request request)
> at Twilio.Rest.Conversations.V1.Conversation.ParticipantResource.Create(CreateParticipantOptions options, ITwilioRestClient client)

Here is my code:

```
TwilioClient.Init(_appSettingService.TWilioAccountSid, _appSettingService.TwilioAuthToken);

var participant = ParticipantResource.Create(
      messagingBindingAddress: "+14704318899",
      messagingBindingProxyAddress: _appSettingService.TwilioPhoneNumber,
      pathConversationSid: "CHec09eb5ef6474f25b6e8dd0ea79affb6"
)
```

Comment: Do ```+14704318899``` is a twilio number ?

Comment: No, it's my personal number.

Comment: @FolabiAhn, can you redact your personal phone number so we can't see it?
What version of the Twilio SDK are you using?

Comment: The phone number is fake. Not my real phone number.

Comment: @levj1 great, what version of the Twilio SDK are you using?

Comment: I had the wrong twillio phone number in there. The issue has been fixed.